# Installing Ivy plugin in Grails 1.1.1: Ivy zip file not found

Tags: grails, ivy

I am using Grails 1.1.1 and I want to install ivy-0.1 but when I run `grails install-plugin ivy` it hits the `http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivy/2.0.0-rc1/apache-ivy-2.0.0-rc1-bin-with-deps.zip`. But here this Zip is not present. Is there any way I can configure the grails repository path so that it hits that url?

OR

Can I first I download the file at my server and configure grails to fetch locally?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/Ivy+Integration) you don't need to install the ivy plug-in in Version 1.1.

> Ivy Support in Grails 1.1
>
> With Grails 1.1, Grails features Ivy support out of the box so you
>   don't need the Ivy plugin. Simply using the Ant build.xml and ivy.xml
>   created by Grails' create-app command.